# Can I change the icon/artwork of an iTunes playlist programmatically?

Tags: winapi, itunes, itunes-sdk

iTunes allows users to set artwork associated with a playlist. However, the iTunes COM library doesn't have any [documentation](http://www.joshkunz.com/iTunesControl/) on this.

Is there a way to set iTunes playlist artwork programmatically?

Comment: Frankly, I have no idea. But to give you a hint that my be useful: the [documentation](http://www.joshkunz.com/iTunesControl/) - which doesn't look to be "officially" from Apple BTW - claims to be _"Generated on Fri Mar 13 12:50:54 2009 for iTunes 8.1.0.52"_ which is a rather old version of iTunes (and itself 11 years only). Maybe the feature you talk about was not available back than in iTunes itself. I would look for a version of the "COM library" (or documentation for that matter) that is for a recent version of iTunes.

Comment: The latest documentation can be found on Apple's developer website, but the only documentation it contains about artwork is about track artwork, and it doesn't mention playlist artwork. Thanks for the idea, though. I'll look around some more for some more documentation or forums.